# How to interpret predicted intraindividual variance (residual variance)?

Tags: variance, multilevel-analysis, heterogeneity

**Background**

I'm working on a project on modeling/understanding the intraindividual variance of a repeat measurement. To do this, I'm following a tutorial set out by Dr. Nilam Ram that can be found [here](https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/sites/qdev/files/ILD_Ch06_2017_MLMwithHeterogeneousVariance.html) which used variance heterogeneity models. Specifically, I am interested in how levels of an antibody affects the intra-individual variation of an inflammatory cell (which uses the antibody as a receptor) on repeat measurement. There's clinical importance to the variability of this inflammatory cell, hence this project. The units I will use in this will be cells/ul for the inflammatory cell and IU/ml for the antibody.

**Data and Preprocessing**

This is an abbreviated data set, changed slightly due to this being Personal Health Information. The variables are as follows: EOS, which is the inflammatory cell repeat measurements. IgE, which is the antibody levels. PID, which is patient ID marker.

```
# Data and preprocessing
library(SciViews)
data = structure(list(PID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 55L, 55L, 
55L, 55L, 55L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 
78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 86L, 86L, 
86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 
94L, 94L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 88L, 88L, 
88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 
64L, 64L, 64L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 
52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 63L, 63L, 
63L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 81L, 
81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 
53L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 72L, 72L, 
72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L), EOS = c(224L, 
374L, 400L, 394L, 198L, 329L, 325L, 147L, 145L, 234L, 273L, 196L, 
249L, 222L, 182L, 215L, 248L, 566L, 192L, 459L, 382L, 205L, 177L, 
249L, 211L, 98L, 300L, 200L, 300L, 200L, 0L, 216L, 330L, 14L, 
200L, 600L, 400L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 100L, 200L, 192L, 122L, 
183L, 157L, 125L, 178L, 125L, 185L, 376L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 
65L, 104L, 69L, 94L, 55L, 100L, 56L, 98L, 131L, 328L, 446L, 281L, 
252L, 100L, 153L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 500L, 100L, 400L, 400L, 88L, 
281L, 297L, 0L, 296L, 106L, 172L, 409L, 704L, 0L, 0L, 131L, 23L, 
51L, 269L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 700L, 400L, 
100L, 100L, 22L, 100L, 374L, 0L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 134L, 400L, 
200L, 400L, 100L, 300L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 400L, 1766L, 316L, 
1007L, 714L, 900L, 600L, 700L, 400L, 181L, 98L, 500L, 300L, 1000L, 
449L, 600L, 42L, 12L, 78L, 154L, 187L, 252L, 140L, 153L, 100L, 
56L, 618L, 200L, 86L, 0L, 100L, 69L, 100L, 65L, 191L, 116L, 96L, 
157L, 142L, 166L, 143L, 138L, 190L, 260L, 216L, 179L, 176L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 300L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 192L, 118L, 177L, 137L, 
150L, 192L, 118L, 177L, 148L, 137L, 150L, 200L, 200L, 173L, 237L, 
146L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 255L, 300L, 
200L, 200L, 300L, 100L, 185L, 148L, 302L, 157L, 105L, 114L, 34L, 
106L, 139L, 224L, 105L, 300L, 200L, 128L, 193L, 109L, 59L, 173L, 
38L, 258L, 307L, 330L, 400L, 400L, 112L, 66L, 98L, 141L, 113L, 
100L, 100L, 300L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 88L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 300L, 123L, 158L, 57L, 182L, 100L, 211L, 99L, 179L, 137L, 
158L, 119L, 232L, 11L, 83L, 77L, 77L, 70L, 95L, 46L, 87L, 79L, 
137L, 67L, 86L, 172L, 172L, 74L, 83L, 81L, 76L, 78L, 140L, 108L, 
81L, 85L, 103L, 97L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 37L, 64L, 66L, 107L, 
100L, 90L, 68L, 105L, 138L, 159L, 166L, 99L, 92L, 0L, 130L, 62L, 
122L, 227L, 231L, 90L, 136L, 134L, 362L, 551L, 354L, 168L, 211L, 
341L, 100L, 0L, 100L, 52L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 
19L, 0L, 21L, 32L, 200L, 146L, 81L, 160L, 168L, 78L, 80L, 54L, 
168L, 77L, 100L, 43L, 100L, 49L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
169L, 136L, 166L, 82L, 170L, 109L, 51L, 204L, 148L, 130L, 169L, 
61L, 139L, 99L, 59L, 92L, 82L, 118L, 210L, 172L, 133L, 13L, 49L, 
51L, 12L, 12L, 109L, 879L, 593L, 645L, 593L, 588L, 379L, 530L, 
73L, 10L, 31L, 106L, 234L, 118L, 202L, 150L, 133L, 141L, 300L, 
353L, 218L, 200L, 64L, 133L, 174L, 117L, 143L, 107L, 106L, 152L, 
211L, 173L, 118L, 60L, 177L, 171L, 106L, 150L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 
200L, 100L, 300L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 101L, 177L, 469L, 600L, 300L, 500L, 300L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 300L, 100L, 90L, 133L, 
200L, 100L, 100L, 46L, 148L, 54L, 83L, 100L, 57L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 72L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 132L, 7L, 63L, 114L, 73L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 169L, 130L, 22L, 13L, 
42L, 198L, 198L, 300L, 200L, 300L, 101L, 92L, 200L, 100L, 300L, 
0L, 53L, 72L, 122L, 143L, 200L, 200L, 108L, 80L, 50L, 22L, 11L, 
36L, 6L, 12L, 85L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 100L), IGE = c(7200L, 7200L, 7200L, 
7200L, 7200L, 7200L, 3722L, 3722L, 3722L, 3722L, 3722L, 3722L, 
3722L, 3722L, 3722L, 3722L, 3722L, 3722L, 3722L, 3722L, 3722L, 
3722L, 3722L, 3722L, 3722L, 2887L, 2887L, 2887L, 2887L, 2887L, 
2887L, 2887L, 2887L, 2887L, 2691L, 2691L, 2691L, 2691L, 2691L, 
2691L, 2691L, 2691L, 2691L, 2042L, 2042L, 2042L, 2042L, 2042L, 
2042L, 2042L, 2042L, 2042L, 2042L, 2042L, 2042L, 2042L, 1849L, 
1849L, 1849L, 1849L, 1849L, 1849L, 1849L, 1849L, 1849L, 1424L, 
1424L, 1424L, 1424L, 1424L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 
1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 
1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 
1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 1093L, 
1093L, 1093L, 1066L, 1066L, 1066L, 1066L, 1066L, 1066L, 1066L, 
1066L, 829L, 829L, 829L, 829L, 829L, 829L, 829L, 829L, 829L, 
724L, 724L, 724L, 724L, 724L, 724L, 724L, 724L, 724L, 550L, 550L, 
550L, 550L, 550L, 550L, 527L, 527L, 527L, 527L, 527L, 527L, 527L, 
527L, 527L, 509L, 509L, 509L, 509L, 509L, 509L, 509L, 509L, 455L, 
455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 
455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 401L, 
401L, 401L, 401L, 401L, 348L, 348L, 348L, 348L, 348L, 348L, 298L, 
298L, 298L, 298L, 298L, 288L, 288L, 288L, 288L, 288L, 288L, 288L, 
288L, 269L, 269L, 269L, 269L, 269L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 
267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 267L, 
258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 215L, 215L, 
215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 
215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 210L, 210L, 210L, 210L, 
210L, 210L, 210L, 210L, 210L, 210L, 210L, 210L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 
204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 
204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 
204L, 204L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 156L, 
156L, 156L, 156L, 156L, 156L, 156L, 156L, 156L, 156L, 156L, 156L, 
156L, 156L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 
152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 
151L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 
143L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 133L, 133L, 
133L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 
116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 
116L, 116L, 116L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
95L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 53L, 
53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 
53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 
49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-518L)))


data$IGE <- as.numeric(ln(data$IGE + 1))
data$IGE_c <- data$IGE - mean(data$IGE, na.rm=TRUE)
data$EOS <- ln(data$EOS + 1)
```

**What I have done**

I followed the tutorial, namely the end that focused on the continuous predictor of heterogenous variance. For your convenience, I've copied the code I used from the tutorial below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(nlme)

# Continuous predictor for within person variance, common between-person differences
model = lme(fixed = EOS ~ 1 + IGE_c,
               random = list(PID = pdSymm(form = ~ 1)),
               weights = varExp(form = ~ IGE_c),
               data = data,
               na.action = na.exclude,
               method = 'REML')

#make a data frame with predictions and back-transform centered variable to original scale.
IgE_c <- seq(-2.0, 7.5, .1)
varpred <- summary(model)$sigma^2 * exp(coef(2*model$modelStruct$varStruct, uncons = FALSE)*IgE_c)
plotvars <- as.data.frame(cbind(IgE_c, varpred))
plotvars$IGE <- plotvars$IgE_c + mean(data$IGE, na.rm=TRUE)
names(plotvars) <- c("IgE", "varpred")


#plotting
ggplot(data = plotvars, aes(x=exp(IgE), y = exp(varpred)), legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  xlab("Serum Antibody Levels") +
  ylab("Predicted IIV in Repeat Eosinophil Count") ## what does this mean?
```

**My Questions**

1. My data is log-normal, therefore I did the modeling on the ln(x+1) of the data. To account for this, I raised e to the x and y axis in the ggplot argument. Was this acceptable/good practice?
2. What exactly is the interpretation of the y-axis in my plot? For instance, is it that measuring the antibody levels to be ~1500 IU/ml would correspond to expected ~6 cells/ul of variation on repeat measurement?

Comment: Question #1 is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30728.  Question #2 is addressed in [many threads,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Interpret+log%28x%29%2B1) such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576504.